# pandas rename column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code: `buckets = pd.DataFrame(sample.score.unique())`

Which produces:

```
        0
0   0.342
1   0.408
2   0.450
3   0.458
4   0.492
5   0.500
```

When I try to rename the column with `buckets.rename(columns = {'0': 'score'}, inplace = True)` the column name `0` is not renamed to `score`.

How can rename `0` to `score`?

Comment: you tryed without the quotes on zero? `{0: 'scores'}`

Comment: @Terry Oh, bother. Yes, that was it. Post answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case just remove the quotes on column name

```
{0: 'scores'}
```